# Hibernate 5 id uniqueness

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-5.x

In Hibernate 5 is it a problem if I use the same id value in different tables?

I have two entities with this annotation:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
public String getId()
{
     return id;
}
```

If I call `session.get(MyClass.class, "theId")` I can get the right entity?

Comment: Yes you get the right entity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create such mappings because

- two classes in Java may have a field with the same name
- two tables in database may have a column with the same name

There is nothing else to it.